# Angular model won't register

Tags: angularjs

Why does clicking the button add two empty strings to the html page rather than the appropriate quote?

Service:

```
quotes.addData = function(quote){
     quotesArr.push(quote);
 }
```

Controller:

```
$scope.quoteToAdd = {
    author : $scope.quoteAuthor,
    text: $scope.quoteText
  };
 $scope.addQuote = quoteService.addData;
}
```

HTML:

```
Author :<input type="text" ng-show="showAdd" ng-model='quoteAuthor' name="name" value="">

  Quote:<input type="text" ng-show="showAdd" ng-model='quoteText' name="name" value=""> 

  <button ng-click='addQuote(quoteToAdd)' ng-show="showAdd" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: $scope.addQuote = quoteService.addData; has no sense, your service isn't returning anything

Comment: could you please provide your full code and moreover are u returning the array from the service?

Comment: I should have said it is a factory and not a service. I tried to post more code and was unable to, but the   $scope.remove = quoteService.removeData function works fine- the factory does work and is returning an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong ng-model bindings in your form:

```
Author :<input type="text" ng-show="showAdd" ng-model='quoteToAdd.author' name="name" value="">

  Quote:<input type="text" ng-show="showAdd" ng-model='quoteToAdd.text' name="name" value=""> 

  <button ng-click='addQuote(quoteToAdd)' ng-show="showAdd" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
```

The above code you have since the controller object is initialized by value of the scope properties initially not by reference.  The new controller listed below should work for what you want done.

Controller (new):

```
$scope.quoteToAdd = {
    author : null,
    text: null
  };
 $scope.addQuote = quoteService.addData;
}
```

Controller (old):

```
$scope.quoteToAdd = {
    author : $scope.quoteAuthor,
    text: $scope.quoteText
  };
 $scope.addQuote = quoteService.addData;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, great explanation.

Comment: No problem let me know if you have other angular related questions.